# Problems with BMP

Tags: c++, bmp

Wrote a simple BMP generation code but instead of outputting what I want (red that gradually goes to black (from left to right)) it returns an image with some some weird layout far from what I expect to see. Was inspecting the way header and pixels written in the memory and everything seems alright

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD6Eh.png)

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

size_t width = 1000, height = 1000, CPP = 3;

//this creates an array of pixels
//supposed to be from red to black from left to right
uint8_t* createBitMapI(const size_t& width, const size_t& height)
{
    uint8_t _color[3] = { 255, 0, 0 };
    uint8_t* bitMap = new uint8_t[width * height * 3];
    //creating one row 
    for (float i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        *(bitMap + (int)(i * 3)) = (uint8_t)_color[0] * (1 - i / width);
        *(bitMap + 1 + (int)(i * 3)) = 0;//(uint8_t)_color[1] * (1 - i / width);
        *(bitMap + 2 + (int)(i * 3)) = 0;//(uint8_t)_color[2] * (1 - i / width);
    }
    //copying previously created row to others
    for (size_t i = 1; i < height; i++)
    {
        memcpy(bitMap + (width * 3) * i, bitMap, width * 3);
    }

    return bitMap;
}

//creates BMP file and writes contents into it
class BMP
{
public:
    BMP(const size_t& width, const size_t& height,
        uint8_t* arr, const char* name)
    {
        const char pad_[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
        char padding = (4 - width % 4) % 4;
        fullSize = (width + padding) * height * 3 + 54;
        image.open(name);
        writeHeader();
        image.write((const char*)header, 54);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            image.write((const char*)arr + (i * width), width * 3);
            image.write(pad_, padding);
        }
        image.close();
    }
    void writeHeader()
    {
        memcpy(header, "BM", 2);
        *(size_t*)(header + 2) = fullSize;
        *(size_t*)(header + 10) = 54;
        *(size_t*)(header + 14) = 40;
        *(size_t*)(header + 18) = width;
        *(size_t*)(header + 22) = height;
        *(uint16_t*)(header + 26) = 1;
        *(uint16_t*)(header + 28) = 24;
    }
private:
    std::ofstream image;
    uint8_t header[54];
    uint8_t* pixels;
    size_t fullSize;
};

int main()
{
    uint8_t* arr = createBitMapI(width, height);
    BMP newImage(width, height, arr, "image.bmp");
    delete[] arr;
}
```

upd: changing `image.open(name)` to `image.open(name, std::ios::binary)` gives us [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gCWO.png)

Comment: [OT]: You might use `std::vector` (or smart pointer) instead of raw owning pointer.

Comment: you probably need to open `image` in binary mode

Comment: `*(size_t*)(header + 2) = fullSize;` has several issues: strict-aliasing violation (including alignment), endianess issue, `sizeof(size_t)`...

Comment: Use of `size_t` in the header is dubious.  Those fields are probably 32-bit.

Comment: Which of the 7 different DIB section headers are you trying to write, it's hard to check the code without knowing see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_(bitmap_information_header)

Comment: @RichardCritten I used this as a reference for writing a header (BITMAPFILEHEADER & BITMAPINFOHEADER if I understand you correct) https://web.archive.org/web/20080912171714/http://www.fortunecity.com/skyscraper/windows/364/bmpffrmt.html

Comment: Copying `width * 3` bytes for every pixel in the image seems wrong. Aside: please do use the official BMP structures defined in [windows.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd183376(v=vs.85)) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @InternalServerError it's not for every pixel but every row of pixels. Just writing the first row and copying its values to other rows to simplify code a bit

Comment: It's inside the nested loop, though.

Comment: Using a for-loop with floats is not particularly wise.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError assuming they are on windows?

Comment: @sehe: including `windows.h` would not preclude the code from being compiled for/running on something else, would it?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thank you for pointing out, while writing question added it as a nested loop by accident. Though it doesn't change the result in any way

Comment: You're also writing the width and height as size_t when the correct type is uint16_t and the height is at offset 20, not 22. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Have you tried? I'm pretty sure I did long time ago, and no, windows.h is not a portable header (surprising, I know)

Comment: @sehe:  `Have you tried?` - I have not, I must admit.